# Huge org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader showing memory usage and its growing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am seeing huge memory gradually increasing for my spring boot app without any load. I have taken heap dumps without any load on application. I can see org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader coming in leak suspect. Memory usage is gradually increasing without any load.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnjQE.png)

App is running with below config

- name: JAVA_OPTS
  value: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0
  -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+StartAttachListener

resources:
limits:
cpu: "1"
memory: 1Gi
requests:
cpu: 500m
memory: 512Mi

Please help me.

Also I have upgraded my spring boot application to **SB version to 2.3.7.RELEASE**

Comment: Can you describe exactly how the memory footprint grow? Does it stop at some level or continue forever?

Comment: Its starting from 700mb and going till 1.13GB. app is not crashing because of it...But I wanted to have less memory.